# Add a hot / popular sort option to the tags page

Tags: feature-request, tags

The popular tags page https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular lists tags ordered by number of questions asked.

The page also displays in most cases how many times it was asked today and this week. I noticed that many of tags have a much higher "questions per week" than tags above it.

To me this signals that the tag is currently hot. For example if you reorder the top 55 tags by week and compared this week rank to the overall rank and only included tags that had a difference of greater than 5 you would come up with this list currently.

```
Tag                  Overall rank  Week Rank  Difference
-------------------- ------------- ---------  ----------
android              9             3          6
objective-c          15            9          6
ios                  32            18         14
ruby-on-rails-3      53            21         32
xcode                40            25         15
visual-studio-2010   54            34         20
json                 52            38         14
web-services         47            41         6
pearl                51            46         5
```

I find this information very interesting.

As an alternative the tags page could just be sorted by questions per week. Since it clear that this data is already being used I would be surprised if this had a perf impact on the database.

Answer (score 1):

I think they could do this on the main Stack Exchange site, and have a dropdown, so you could choose any site you wanted.