# Getting stats on questions for a given technology

Tags: feature-request, statistics

Is there any way to get statistics on the popularity or relevance of various technologies? For example: How many questions have been asked on QT over the last 6 months. How many views on these questions?

I'm trying to decide whether a given software technology is holding its own or the community is losing interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query [Questions per tag last 6 months](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1919/questions-per-tag-last-6-months) and [Question Views per tag last 6 months](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1920/question-views-per-tag-last-6-months) should get you started.

Also the tag page https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=3&tab=popular is more current, but you can only see how many are asked in the day, week and alltime. However you can see how its trending by comparing tags that are near it.

I'm still hoping that that implement [additional sorting on that page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99356/feature-request-hot-tags-or-popular-tags-sorted-by-week). (Maybe someone can just do a stack app for that)

Comment: Thanks Conrad.  I had to learn SQL but it worked really well.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm trying to decide whether a given software technology is holding its own or the community is losing interest.

Personally, I think such statistics gathered from the Stack Exchange Network are meaning less. But feel free to use the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to create them.