# Is there any way to view "fastest growing" tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I like to stay on edge of new technologies, at least knowing that they exist. Therefore, as a user of Stack Overflow, I'd like to be able to see what tags are growing the fastest.

I know there's a small line on the tags page saying "X asked today, Y asked this week", but I'd have to go through a lot of pages to find the ones that have an interesting number compared to the total number of questions tagged with it.

So I was thinking about a page that would list tags according to their % growth over a length of time we can choose from (day/week/month/year maybe). Filtering out tags with less than X questions might help, otherwise we'd see crazy numbers for new tags.

Is this something that could be of interest? Or am I the only one interested? Is there any way to do it already?

Comment: Related [Feature Request: Hot Tags or Popular tags sorted by week](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99356/148672)

Comment: I'm guessing someone with more skill than I could figure this out using the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'd love to see something around this get implemented buty ou can use or modify this [data.se query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/76245/top-tags-for-a-given-week?year=2012&month=17) in the mean time

Comment: It's a start, thanks !

Comment: `Fastest growing tags == most popular technologies with biggest problems and/or greatest number of unqualified users`.

Comment: I'd add and/or new technologies (which implies the other conditions anyway)

Comment: @RobertHarvey that may be so but you can tease out interesting [time localized trends](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/76263/hot-tags?year=2012&week=17&overalRankMin=500). For example [Phonegap](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/phonegap/info) (overall ranked 242) had a similar week to perl (58) cocoa (56) and visual-studio (87) on the 17th week of 2012. Does phonegap meet your requirements? I don't know I've never heard of it before today.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1631321/fastest-growing-tags?DateFrom=2022-01-01&NumberOfDays=31&MinimumOccurrence=100&ReferenceDateFrom=2021-01-01) is an attempt at such an analysis with the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). You can tweak the parameters if you want to, but the query might time out on Stack Overflow if you choose a period that is too long or a threshold that is too low. These are the tags that saw the biggest increase from January 2022 compared to January 2021 (while being used 100 times or more in both periods):

[image]

Note that SEDE is updated only once a week, on Sunday morning, so don't try to analyze last week.